# Install Android SDK problem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, software-installation, android

everyone. I am trying to set up android-studio on my Linux mint 19.3 trica.

I almost done installing. But stuck at SDK installing; clearly my system doesn't contain valid SDK. But the installation procedure doesn't show the available candidate, I try to switch the install directory, sometimes the hint say the directory  is empty or doesn't contain valid SDK, the download size are 0. I have used it in my formal Linux mint system and it is OK. Is this a common problem. Although the problem are not really related to Linux, but I think it is reasonable to ask question there.

Comment: How are you installing it? Have you tried the flatpak version?

Comment: No, I did not. I just unpack the archive on the official website, and run its install script. I will give it a try

Comment: I have tried it, in fact I am trying to install the android-stuio on  different Linux mint 19.3 instance from the flakpak store and the website archive. Both end with same kind of problem. Just tell me SDK missing but don not give me a chance in SDK set up step.Accept one of my computer success with no apparent reason.